# Saving image in canvas to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, local-storage

I'm trying to save my drawn circles on my canvas to the localstorage, but I just can't get it to work, at all.

So far this is my save-code in JS.

```
function saveCanvas() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCanvas"),
    doomslayer = canvas.toDataURL();

 if (typeof (localStorage) !== "undefined") {

    localStorage.setItem('imgCanvas', doomslayer);
 } else {
    document.getElementById("save").innerHTML.dataURL = "Local Storage not supported";
   }
}

function loadCanvas() {

var image = localStorage.getItem('imgCanvas');

document.getElementById('imgCanvas').src = image;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Xv6wN/5/)

Got it to work now, finally! 
[Working fiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/ttn87/3/)

Comment: There's no `src` attribute in `HTMLCanvasElement`. You'll have to set the data url to an `<img>`.

Comment: I just can't get it to work, i tried that before and I tried it again now, nothing. @Passerby

Comment: @DaveKarlsson How did you try?

Comment: @Passerby Nevemind, finally got it to work. :)

Answer (score 3):

You must load the saved data url into an Image and then use drawImage to load it onto the canvas

IE limitation:  localStorage is only available on a served page (local execution won't work!).

```
// save to localStorage

localStorage.setItem("imgCanvas",canvas.toDataURL());

// reload from localStorage

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src=localStorage.getItem("imgCanvas");
```