# is it possible to save entire canvas into Local storageand retrieve canvas from Local storage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to save entire canvas into Local storage and retrieve canvas from local storage.

I am trying using following code

```
function saveBoard(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvid1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.save();   

    var drawingSurfaceImageData = context.getImageData(
        0, 0,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height);

    if (typeof (localStorage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('imgCanvas',drawingSurfaceImageData);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML.dataURL = "Local Storage not supported";
    }   
}

function restoreBoard() {
    alert("in restore");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvid1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var  data = localStorage.getItem("imgCanvas");
    alert("data"+data);
    context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with that code?

Comment: Copying a [problematic code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603222/saving-image-in-canvas-to-local-storage) from a question is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. Keep in mind that the local storage for one origin is not allowed to be bigger than 5MB! You can test the capacity for your browser on this [site](https://arty.name/localstorage.html). You should also check if the item you try to get from the local storage is not undefined.

```
function restoreBoard() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvid1"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      data = localStorage.getItem("imgCanvas");

  if(data){
    context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
  }else{
    console.log('No data saved.')
  }

}
```

EDIT:

Also dont store the image data, store the base64 encoded image. You can achieve this the following way:

```
function saveBoard(e) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvid1"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.save();   

  var imageBase64String = canvas.toDataURL(); // get the base64 string from the canvas context

  if (typeof (localStorage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem('imgCanvas',imageBase64String );
  } else {
    document.getElementById("save").innerHTML.dataURL = "Local Storage not supported";
  }   
}
```

And you restore it the following way:

```
function restoreBoard() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvid1"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      data = localStorage.getItem("imgCanvas");

  if(data){
    context.drawImage(data, 0, 0); // draw the base64 encoded image on the canvas
  }else{
    console.log('No data saved.')
  }

}
```

Comment: i tried same but giving same error when i tried to save data into local storage it store it as Image data, but when i get back and try to put it on canvas it showing error as TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData is not an object.

Comment: What does the error say, when you put it into localStorage? When there is an error while storing, you won't get the image data back and the function throws this error.